# Getting a 404 error for really basic flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm just getting started with Flask and am following this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-web-application-using-flask-and-deploy-it-to-the-cloud-3551c985e492/

This is all that I have so far in my code

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!"


@app.route("/salvador")
def salvador():
    return "Hello, Salvador"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It routes correctly to "/", but then I'm getting the 404 error whenever I try to go "/salvador". Any suggestions on why I'm getting this?

Comment: Works for me. Use URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/salvador

Comment: Thanks, I figured out what was wrong with it, it wasn't saving properly to my file even though I had pressed save.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me but sometimes small things such as an extra slash can end up on a 404

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2020 01:34:15] "GET /salvador HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2020 01:34:19] "GET /salvador/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```